# Use Javascript to Click All Google Chrome "Show Password" Icons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In a Chrome browser, when in Settings > Manage passwords:
chrome://settings/passwords a "Show Password" icon exists

[image: show passwords chrome]

I have to manually click each "eye" icon for the input field to change from a readonly `type="password"` to `type="text"` and display the password.

I'm curious how I could use javascript to click all icons to show all my saved passwords for each site in one go.

```
<div class="password-column">
  <input id="password" aria-label="Password" class="password-field" readonly=""
         type="password" disabled="">
  <paper-icon-button-light id="showPasswordButtonContainer" class="icon-visibility">
    <button id="showPasswordButton" focus-row-control="" focus-type="showPassword"
            title="Show password" tabindex="0">
      <paper-ripple class="circle"></paper-ripple>
    </button>
  </paper-icon-button-light>
  <template is="dom-if"></template>
  <span class="password-field text-elide" id="federated" hidden=""></span>
</div>
```

For some reason, I can't seem to even select the elements when using Chrome Javascript *console* inside Chrome:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById("showPasswordButton");
```

The variable `buttons` is `null`.

This is more of a curiosity question for me than anything. I'm currently a Javascript beginner with a good Python background.

Comment: You can't select them like that because they're in shadow DOM.

Comment: If you're not aware, Chrome has an `Export passwords` button on that page :)

Comment: @JoshLee I actually wasn't aware of that. Thanks for pointing that out. Wasn't obvious to me with three vertical dots representing a menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't select those elements because they're in shadow DOM.

You could try the shadow-piercing descendant combinator `/deep/`, although its fate is uncertain as that was part of V0 and not V1 shadow DOM. (For example, you can only use it from `querySelector`, not from a stylesheet.) Still, Chrome supports it for time being.

```
> document.querySelectorAll('* /deep/ button#showPasswordButton[title="Show password"]')
NodeList(41)
```

(Filtering out those whose title is instead `Hide password`).

From the devtools API we also have access to Chrome's `queryObjects` function, which will find all instances of a particular type in memory.

```
> queryObjects(HTMLButtonElement)
undefined
Array(122)
```

The evaluation of `queryObjects` is slightly weird, (that `undefined` in the middle is a clue) so we have to *right click > Store as global variable* to bind it to a name (both `temp1` and `$_`, conveniently).

```
temp1
> $_.filter(b => b.id=='showPasswordButton' && b.title=='Show password')
(41)
```

You might notice that the number of buttons is much smaller than the actual size of the list, since Polymer is rendering them on the fly as you scroll through. You could pause the evaluation when clicking on this button to discover the underlying data model, and you can look around in the debugger or the source code to discover what it's doing, but I'll leave a few more expressions here to play with:

```
> passwordManager = document.querySelector('* /deep/ passwords-section').passwordManager_
PasswordManagerImpl {}
> await new Promise(resolve => passwordManager.getPlaintextPassword(0, resolve))
{index: 0, plaintextPassword: "cisco"}
```

Or `queryObjects(PasswordManagerImpl)`, again to bypass the DOM and find objects in the heap more freely.

If `/deep/` goes away without any replacement, we could try using the TreeWalker/NodeIterator interface to open each `shadowRoot` in turn, recursively.